# The member 'value' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_iterables/rx_list.dart'

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for my project.

I have a little warning with RxList in GetX.

How do I fix this warning?

[image: warning]

This is my code:

```
var questionListItems = RxList<QuestionLookupResponse>();
// ....
Future<void> onInit() async {
  if (questionListItems.value.isNotEmpty) { // <--- Warning
    questionListItems.value.clear(); // <--- Warning
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `.value` . It work. Because  `Rxlist` can be accesses without value.. So... You can use `Rxlist` directly like list

Comment: You may refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460163/the-member-value-can-only-be-used-within-instance-members-of-subclasses-with-f/69523101#69523101

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove `.value`. It work. Because `Rxlist` can be accesses without `.value`. So... You can use `Rxlist` directly like list

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: For RxList use .toList()

Answer (score 4):

As '@Giacomo A.' said in a comment, I had to use **.toList()** to make it observe my RwList changes. If it can help some people who, like me, were struggling with this problem for a few days :D Thank you Giacomo :)

Comment: .toList() saved my day