# The member 'value' can only be used within instance members of subclasses with flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, obs

i have encounterd this problem in this example:

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {

  final storage =  const FlutterSecureStorage();
  var authData = [].obs;
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  var authLoading = false.obs;

  @override
  onInit() {
    authUser();
    super.onInit();
  }

   authUser() async {
     var all =  await storage.readAll();
    authData.value = all.entries
        .map((e) => AuthModel(key: e.key, value: e.value)).toList(growable: false);

  }

   bool isAuth() {
    var a = isLoading.value.isBlank;
  return authData.value.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

here in this line:

```
return authData.value.isNotEmpty;
```

IDE add line under (value) and warning like this:

```
The member 'value' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_iterables/rx_list.dart'.
```

how can i solve this problem? or just work around it? >>> Thank you in advace

Comment: You generally subscribe to observables, not access the value raw.

Comment: but it is work without any problem except this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lists** are reactive by default. Therefore unlike other observables, you don't need to use `.value` to access the list. But you need to use `.obs` when declaring them.

Or you can use something like this if you want to use `.value` too with lists:

```
final authData = RxList([]);
```

***Update***

The reason why it doesn't work correctly and as expected because of this:

```
authData.value = all.entries
    .map((e) => AuthModel(key: e.key, value: e.value)).toList(growable: false);
```

In case of setting the value of **RxLists** you should use `assignAll` method on the RxList like this:

```
authData.assignAll(all.entries
    .map((e) => AuthModel(key: e.key, value: e.value)).toList(growable: false));
```

Comment: without .value it doesn't work correctly and as expected.... and with final authData = RxList([]); it also show me same problem

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks pal ..... it worked